# Use (print) a variable that has neither been initialized nor assigned a value?

Tags: flutter, dart

The below code gives an error in the dart pad.

```
void main( )
{
   int num;
   print(num);
}
```

> Error compiling to JavaScript:
> Warning: Interpreting […]
> Error: Non-nullable variable 'n' must be assigned before it can be used.
>   `print(n);`
>         `^`  
> Error: Compilation failed

Is it impossible to print a variable that has no assigned a value and is not initialized before in dart?

Comment: No, you can't.  What would you expect to be printed?  Accessing uninitialized variables is an error.  Either explicitly initialize it or use a nullable type.

Comment: I read somewhere that if a variable is not initialized then it will print Null in the console. Here I was trying to verify it, but it didn't work.

Comment: That was true *before* Dart 2.12, which introduced [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) and non-nullable types by default.

Comment: The title contains entirely too many negations.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is because of the null safety of flutter. You could turn it off in the lower left of DartPad and then use a variable without prior assignment or initialisation.

You can however indicate that a variable might have the value `null`,
**just append `?`** to its type declaration.

```
void main()
{
   int? num;
   print(num);
}
```

[More info about null-safety in Flutter](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

Comment: thanks for the solution, now it is showing the null in the console.

Comment: No problem, could you flag my answer as a solution?

Comment: How to do that? 
Actually I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a variable once it is guaranteed to be initialized:

Here, `i` is guaranteed to be *uninitialized*, so cannot be used.

```dart
int i;
print(i);  // compile error
```

Here, `i` might be initialized, but it also might not be, so it cannot be used:

```dart
int i;
if (Random().nextBool() {
  i = 1;
}
print(i);  // compile error
```

Here, `i` is definitely initialized, so *can* be used:

```dart
int i;
if (Random().nextBool() {
  i = 1;
} else {
  i = 2;
}
print(i);  // fine
```

If you have a variable that you know will be initialized before it is used, but the compiler cannot guarantee it, you can use `late` to defer this check until runtime, although it will still fail if the variable is uninitialized.

Nullable types (e.g. `int?`) are initialized to `null` by default:

```dart
int? i;
print(i);  // prints 'null'
```